# Normalizing TypeNats Inequalities

Tags: haskell, types, data-kinds

I have two functions both with a Nat (from TypeNats) kind that both have a comparison type operator `<=`. The constraint `2 <= n` for function `b` contains the constraint `1 <= n` for function `a`. Is there a way to get ghc to resolve that `2 <= n` satisfies the constraint `1 <= n` so that I do not have to specify both `(1 <= n, 2 <= n)` constraints for `b`?

The below code demonstrates the error.

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures, TypeOperators, ScopedTypeVariables, 
             DataKinds, TypeFamilies #-}

import GHC.TypeNats
import Data.Proxy

a :: forall (a :: Nat). 1 <= a => Proxy a -> Int
a = undefined

b :: forall (a :: Nat). 2 <= a => Proxy a -> Int
b = a
```

Results in a compile error

```
• Could not deduce: (1 <=? a) ~ 'True arising from a use of ‘a’
  from the context: 2 <= a
    bound by the type signature for:
               b :: forall (a :: Nat). (2 <= a) => Proxy a -> Int
    at Example.hs:9:1-48
• In the expression: a
  In an equation for ‘b’: b = a
• Relevant bindings include
    b :: Proxy a -> Int
      (bound at Example.hs:10:1)
```

There is a library to solve equalities [ghc-typelits-natnormalise](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-typelits-natnormalise) but not inequalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the package description, `ghc-typelits-natnormalise` can solve inequalities as well.  The following program typechecks with GHC 8.6.4 and `ghc-typelits-natnormalise-0.6.2`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures, TypeOperators, ScopedTypeVariables,
             DataKinds, TypeFamilies #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fplugin GHC.TypeLits.Normalise -Wall #-}

import GHC.TypeNats
import Data.Proxy

a :: forall (a :: Nat). 1 <= a => Proxy a -> Int
a = undefined

b :: forall (a :: Nat). 2 <= a => Proxy a -> Int
b = a
```

Comment: Package `ghc-typelits-presburger` might also do the job.